# linux core dump size doubles

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, stack-dump

I have a rather weird issue at hand. I am trying to setup kdump/kexec with linux 2.6.35-14.

Everything works fine and I am effecting the crash via "echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger".

However, I see that the size of the core file generated DOUBLES for every invocation of crash! :s :s

- First crash: 347Mb
- Second crash: 622Mb
- Third crash: 1.2Gb
- Fourth crash: 2.2Gb

Would folks have any insight into why this could be? And hence what the solution could be?

Thanks much.

Comment: I believe the coredump size depends on the amount of memory use by the application that crashes. MAybe your crash happens in different time and different apps crashing. check this page for info about your coredump: http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/UserInfo/Resources/Hardware/CommonDoc/core.html can be helpful to find out what is crashing.